# How can i sum array elements as an array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

i have two arrays and i want to make calculations with the elements in these arrays.

```
$result1=DB::where('elements',$elements)->get();

$result2=DB::where('otherElements',$otherElements)->get();
```

for example; $result1 = [5,7,9] and $result2 = [0,5,9]

$result3 must be (for multiply) [0,35,81] or (for sum) [5,12,18]

i tried to do with for loop but it does not solve my problem in blade file.

so i want to do it in controller then send the result to the blade file.

Comment: You can use `array_product` or `array_sum` function from php to add or multiply two arrays

Comment: You can achieve this via SQL itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map` same as :

```
$result3 = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
    return $v1 + $v2;
}, $result1, $result2);

$result4 = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
    return $v1 * $v2;
}, $result1, $result2);
```

Code online in [here](https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5VIpSi0uzSkxVLBViDbVMdexjLWGCxqBBA10TCGCcGFjoHBiUVFiZXxuYoFGWmlecklmfp6GSpmhjoJKmZFmNS8XZ1FqSWlRHpBrqKANEgTqrwXKQi2Ds4w0kQ02Ic1gLcIGFxRl5pXEF2nAXA4SRRMz0bQGAA%2C%2C&v=8.1.6)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use array_map and array_sum as:

```
$result1 = [1, 2];
$result2 = [1, 2];

$result3 = array_map(function () {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}, $result1, $result2);

print_r($result3);
```